# Displaying tooltips on tablet readers, specifically iPad

Tags: acrobat, pdfcomment, fancytooltips, acrotex, ipad

I am trying to generate tooltips in a PDF that will be accessible somehow on a tablet PDF reader, specifically on any iPad reader. So far, I have tried the packages [pdfcomment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment), [cooltooltips](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cooltooltips), and [fancytooltips](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips), but none of these were accessible on the iPad with Adobe Reader as a reference.

I am aware that tooltips on a tablet don't make much sense since there is no such thing as a mouse over, but maybe there is something similar that works with a box that opens and closes on click or something. For example, I found something similar for the Safari browser which uses JavaScript's jQuery:

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

Is there any way I could get something like that working or can you think of a reasonable work-around? Or does that actually work already and am I just using the wrong PDF viewer/settings/anything? My current solution would be to use notes at the end of the PDF and [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to jump between pages, but I'd like to have something more elegant.

Thank you for any hints or comments.

Comment: Did you try GoodReader app? It is the most capable pdf reader to my knowledge. In fact, it allows to add notes and highlights to any pdf in a format compatible with (desktop) Adobe Reader, so I guess it should show the ones generated with the packages you mention.

Comment: Mmm.. I tried opening the documentation of `cooltooltip` package in GoodReader. I was unable to read the tooltip, although the text is displayed somewhat different (perhaps because of it is a link). So no, GoodReader is of no help either.

Comment: Did you try to view a PDF file with some OCG (Optional Content Group) layers?

Comment: I have tried that but I can't get any context menu on the iPad A-Reader which would allow me activate or deactivate layers. I have opened a PDF with OCG and it naturally shows all layers. So some activation/deactivation magic might do the trick, but I don't know how I would do that.

Answer (score 4):

The minimal tooltip macro definition below uses mouse-down and up events in addition to roll-over and out for showing/hiding the tooltip. This works in Adobe Reader on my PC. Take it as a proof of concept if it works on a tablet or phone too. In case of multiline tooltips, the tip text should be put into a `\parbox[b]{}{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% usage: \tooltip{<link text>}{<tip text>}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\tooltip[2]{%
  \leavevmode%
  \immediate\pdfobj{<</S/Hide/T (tip\thetcnt)/H false>>}%
  \edef\showaction{\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}%
  \immediate\pdfobj{<</S/Hide/T (tip\thetcnt)/H true>>}%
  \edef\hideaction{\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}%
  \pdfstartlink
    user{
      /FT/Btn/Ff 65536/T(lnk\thetcnt)/H/N
      /Subtype/Widget/AA <<
        /D \showaction /U \hideaction
        /E \showaction /X \hideaction
        /PO \hideaction
      >>
    }{\color{red}#1}%
  \pdfendlink%
  \sbox\tiptext{\colorbox[gray]{0.8}{#2}}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \immediate\pdfxform\tiptext%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#1}}{%
    \pdfannot width \twd height \tht depth \tdp {
      /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/Ff 65537/T (tip\thetcnt)
      /AP <</N \the\pdflastxform\space 0 R>>
    }%
  }%    
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}\Huge
  Einstein's \tooltip{formula}{$E=m c^2$} is well known.
  Another famous formula is due to \tooltip{Pythagoras}{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried your implementation in the A-Reader on my PC and it works like a charm. However, when I tried it on the Adobe Reader on the iPad, the tooltips were initially all activated and when I tried to click on one, the Reader crashed with no error report whatsoever :-(

Comment: The PDF specific stuff in the code is quite conforming to the official spec. So the mobile version of AR must be bugged. The tips should be hidden during the page-open event as specified by the `/PO` entry. Did you try other pdf readers?

Comment: @Michael: What happens if you delete `/E \showaction /X \hideaction` from the code and recompile? Maybe registering the actions for roll-over and out causes problems.

Comment: I have recompiled without `/E \showaction /X \hideaction` but Adobe Reader still crashes on click. I have tried several other readers (DjVu Reader, GoodReader, iAnnotate PDF). They don't crash, but I cannot 'click' on the highlighted words. Touching the screen at those locations seems to do nothing.

Comment: @Michael: What about initial visibility? Are the tips hidden as desired when the document/page is being opened? What about Foxit Reader?

Comment: Foxit Reader does not crash on clicking the highlighted items but also seems to do nothing at all. Tooltips are visible on program start, both in A-Reader and in Foxit. Keeping or removing seems to have no impact on iPad.

Comment: So I am at my wit's end, @Michael. Sorry that we couldn't solve it.

Comment: @Michael: One last thought. Could you try to place the tooltips on the second page of the document ( putting some text and a `\newpage` after `\begin{document}`)?

Comment: I inserted some lorem ipsum and had your example start on page 2. Unfortunately, it produced identical results to the previous tests: tooltips show on start-up and A-Reader crashes on click whereas other readers don't do anything. Thanks again for all the help. At least, it really seems to be a difficult issue.

Comment: @AlexG, very cool. Do you know if your code can be modified to work for tikz objects. This code "almost" work: `\begin{tikzpicture}\tooltip{\draw(0,0)--(1,1);}{a line}\draw(0,1)--(1,0);\end{tikzpicture}` as it highlights one of the lines, but the tooltip appears too small to see the content. I want to solve this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88293/is-is-possible-to-associate-part-of-a-drawing-to-a-pdfcomment-or-similar-inter

Comment: @AlexG, Is this answer equivalent to using the `tooltip` command from `pdfcomment` package?

Comment: `pdfcomment` doesn't produce TeX-formatted text annotations, as far as I know.

Comment: For ***further updates*** of the `\tooltip` command, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111932