# Is it possible to associate part of a drawing to a pdfcomment (or similar) interactive bubble?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdfcomment

It is apparently possible to put a TikZ drawing inside a `pdfcomment` (but using `mbox`).

Is is possible to associate only part of a drawing (e.g. a line) to a `pdfcomment`? Below it is the suggested code.

I am open to use other interactive packages (similar to `pdfcomment`) if that can solve the problem. The final goal is to associate individual curves in a `pgfplot` to a tooltip when dragging the mouse.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}

%ok
\pdfmarkupcomment[]{
    text
}{
    a paragraph
}

% ok but needs mbox
\pdfmarkupcomment[]{
    \mbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(0,0)--(1,1);
    \draw(0,1)--(1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}{
    a drawing
}

%not ok (Error: Missing } inserted.)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pdfmarkupcomment[]{
        \draw(0,0)--(1,1);
    }{
        a line
    }
    \draw(0,1)--(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you will be interested in the `ocgx` package; on this site have a look to [Explanatory bubbles in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83783/explanatory-bubbles-in-beamer#83786) the Interactive word explanation part, [Interactive PDF, Latex and Article of the Future](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84681/interactive-pdf-latex-and-article-of-the-future) and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65096/how-to-make-a-diagram-composed-of-superimposed-layers-where-the-viewer-can-make

Comment: Another possibility is `Acrotex`: see as reference [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, this method looks the most promising http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84754/1871. While `ocg` is probably the most general, I am trying to avoid external scrips and Acrotex dependency.

Comment: Please try the [`fancytooltips`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) package.

Comment: In case someone else tries to follow this route: The approach of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84754/1871 does not work here. While the document compiles and shows the second line in the last example in red, the tooltip itself does not show up when hovering over the line.

Comment: @cryingshadow .. because the right PDF viewer should be used.

Answer (score 5):

This question can be solved in several parts:

## In what extend can pdf comments be part of Ti*k*Z pictures?

As long as the comment is put inside a `node{}`, there is nothing impossible. In fact, you can put almost everything inside a `node{}`. For example:

```
\tikz[remember picture,id=right triangle]{
    \draw(0,0)node[below]{\pdfmarkupcomment[color=yellow]{$A$}{This is (0, 0)}}
       --(6,0)node[right]{\pdfmarkupcomment[color=yellow]{$B$}{This is (6, 0)}}
       --(0,3)node[above]{\pdfmarkupcomment[color=yellow]{$C$}{This is (0, 3)}};
       --cycle
}
```

[image]

## How to make a comment associated to a line/polyline/polygon?

The [pdfcomment](/questions/tagged/pdfcomment) provide `\pdflinecomment` so that you can, according to the manual, **typeset a comment in form of a line, polyline or polygon
at the wished spot of the page**.

For example:

```
\pdflinecomment[type=polyline,opacity=1,color=green,line={
    200 500 260 500 200 530
}]{This is a triangle comment!}
```

[image]

## How to position this comment

From the previous example we see that a line comment is defined by x- and y- coordinates, in `bp`, relative to the lower left corner of this page. But how do we generate these numbers automatically so that the comment coincides with the triangle in Ti*k*Z pucture?

A possibility is that Ti*k*Z has an option called `remember picture` and it will store the position of the Ti*k*Z picture. By using this imformation we have a chance to calculate the coordinates we need.

But instead of doing boring maths, we can fire `\pgfsys@markposition` multiple times so that every position we need are stored. And again, there is nothing impossible if you put them in `node{}`'s:

```
\def\markposition#1{
    \pgfsys@markposition{#1}
}
\tikz{
    \draw(0,0)node{\markposition{point A}}
       --(6,0)node{\markposition{point B}}
       --(0,3)node{\markposition{point C}}
       --cycle;
}
```

And then we can retrieve those coordinate by `\pgfsys@getposition`:

```
\def\getposition#1#2#3{
    \pgfsys@getposition{#1}\pointposition\pointposition
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct\pgf@x\xdef#2{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct\pgf@y\xdef#3{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@y}
}
\getposition{point A}\Ax\Ay
\getposition{point B}\Bx\By
\getposition{point C}\Cx\Cy
```

Now `\Ax` is the x-coordinate of A, and so on. So afterwards we can these coordinates in `\pdflinecomment` as follows:

```
\let~\space
\pdflinecomment[type=polyline,opacity=1,color=blue,line={
    \Ax~\Ay~\Bx~\By~\Cx~\Cy
}]{This is a triangle comment!}
```

[image]

## Can I get rid of the ugly blue drawing?

Change the `opacity`:

[image]

## Full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pdfcomment,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\tikz[remember picture,id=right triangle]{
    \draw(0,0)node[below]{\pdfmarkupcomment[color=yellow]{$A$}{This is (0, 0)}}
       --(6,0)node[right]{\pdfmarkupcomment[color=yellow]{$B$}{This is (6, 0)}}
       --(0,3)node[above]{\pdfmarkupcomment[color=yellow]{$C$}{This is (0, 3)}}
       --cycle;
}

\lipsum[2]

\clearpage

\lipsum[3]

\pdflinecomment[type=polyline,opacity=1,color=green,line={
    200 500 260 500 200 530
}]{This is a triangle comment!}

\lipsum[4]

\clearpage

\lipsum[5]

\makeatletter

\def\markposition#1{
    \pgfsys@markposition{#1}
}
\tikz{
    \draw(0,0)node{\markposition{point A}}
       --(6,0)node{\markposition{point B}}
       --(0,3)node{\markposition{point C}}
       --cycle;
}
\def\getposition#1#2#3{
    \pgfsys@getposition{#1}\pointposition\pointposition
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct\pgf@x\xdef#2{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct\pgf@y\xdef#3{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@y}
}
\getposition{point A}\Ax\Ay
\getposition{point B}\Bx\By
\getposition{point C}\Cx\Cy
\let~\space
\pdflinecomment[type=polyline,opacity=.5,color=blue,line={
    \Ax~\Ay~\Bx~\By~\Cx~\Cy
}]{This is a triangle comment!}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```