# How to return back from reference page to referring page in beamer after seeing the reference?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, back-referencing

We can go to reference page by clicking on the citation number in beamer. Is their a way to return back on referring slide after seeing the reference?

Comment: It's not clear what should happen if you have two links referring to the same thing...

Comment: The best bet would be displaying the reference in a tooltip. This avoids leaving the page. See, e. g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111932

Comment: This is a PDF viewer problem rather than TeX/LaTeX; the correspondence from citation to bibliography item is "many to one", so it's impossible to tell from the bib item where to go back. Just hit the key that brings you to the previous view: every decent PDF previewer has it.

Comment: @egreg, do u know how to go to previous view in document viewer.

Comment: @PrakharBansal: Alt+ArrowLeft in AdobeReader, for example.

Comment: @PrakharBansal It depends on the PDF viewer you're using (and the operating system, too).

Comment: You could also use backreferences (i.e. "see p.15,37,59" at the end of references), which can be hyperlinks as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PDF viewer abilities, not TeX.

Comment: Try this:
Add at one citation before `\cite{myKey1}` a "`\phantomsection`" command and after that a "`\label{BackTo1}`"... like "`\phantomsection\cite{myKey1}\label{backTo1}`" then inside the bibliography add for
`@article{myKey1,
title={Title},
author={Author},
year={year},
...etc...
note={\href{backTo1}{Back To Text}},
}`

NOT TESTED