# interactive tooltipp improvement

Tags: calculations, media9

according to this article, especially to AlexGs tooltipp code [1], it seems to me, that if the text inside the tooltipp will exceed more than one line, it disappears outside the page.
It would be nice, if it would break the yellow box, so that all information can be read.

[1] ["Interactive PDF, Latex and Article of the Future" with opentype/truetype fonts and unicode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111859/interactive-pdf-latex-and-article-of-the-future-with-opentype-truetype-fonts/111932#111932)

@AlexG can you adapt your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip text in the referenced answer is typeset into an LR-box and thus doesn't break across multiple lines. To do this, just put `<tip text>` into a `\parbox` of suitable, i. e. shorter than `\linewidth`, length.

Comment: I do not know, why it works now. I thout about this solution before I asked this question. For sure I have to use my brain in a more intense way. Thank you very much, Alex.