# [fancy-preview]: Mouse-over bibliography citations using Perl from Windows Tex Live, and with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, texlive, windows, perl, fancytooltips

What does one need to do to get the [`fancy-preview`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727480/how-do-i-make-my-perl-scripts-act-like-normal-programs-on-windows) script going
with only a Windows Tex Live installation thus far.

The basics have been discussed on `tex.SE` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig/82352#82352).

[Quick digression: we use bibtex;
does fancy-preview work with bibtex?]

**Installing Perl**:

Windows Tex Live supposedly comes with Perl:

Tex Live's site somewhat ominously states that it comes with "its own version of Perl."
which I take to mean that:

- it comes with Perl, without notable changes, or
- it's a modified version, cooked up to do whatever Windows Tex Live needs.

**Running Perl**:

I tried to run: `perl fancy-preview <filename>`; however,
I received the error `'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

I think I need to link the program to the command prompt somehow.
Any suggestions? [[Closest thing I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727480/how-do-i-make-my-perl-scripts-act-like-normal-programs-on-windows).]

I copied the `..\texlive\2015\tlpkg\tlperl` folder to a local directory,
and I placed my file with the perl.exe binary.

The command prompt then pointed out that `fancy-preview.pl` was not found.

I feel like there's some steps which need to be taken
such that these things are all found.

**Calling these files with Tex Works**:

Also, is there a method to call these straight from TexWorks?
`pdflatex.exe` is called fine enough.
`arara` makes multiple calls even easier.

Is there a method to call `perl fancy-preview` for the file?
Is there a method to automate it into an arara batch?

**Installing Other Prerequisites**:

Besides Perl, the [`fancy-preview`](http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/fancytooltips.pdf) [documentation](http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/fancytooltips.pdf) and [site](http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/)
point out that additional programs are needed (beyond a pdf reader..).

Are these included by default with `fancy-preview.sty`?

The Tex Live manager pulls up `fancy-preview.sty` when I search for them
but this may just be because they are mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: If you don't mind using `biblatex`. there is a user-friendly alternative without the need for external Perl and fancy-preview: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111932

Comment: @AlexG Pfffft. Forget `fancy-preview`. Follow the link above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has decided to use a solution covered in a different Q&A, but this question is not a duplicate because it uses a different system for bibliographies. See comments on question.

Comment: @cfr Is the question off-topic? I was looking for a tooltips bibliography solution, and AlexG informed me that my expected method had been superceded with a much easier method. Can he at least post his comment as an answer, as it will completely solve everything I was concerned about? More importantly, his suggested method wasn't something which was popping up in my searches.

Comment: Do you want to edit the question so @AlexG can sensibly give that answer? Or will that be a duplicate?

Comment: @cfr I misunderstood your reasoning for off-topic; I thought you had meant that this was already answered elsewhere on this Q&A, but I now realize that that would be grounds for marking as duplicate and not off-topic. I believe you are stating this belongs on another Q&A SE site, such as Superuser?

Comment: No. It is just that there are a limited number of reasons for closing a question. When none of them fits, we use one which doesn't really fit and add an explanation in the comment. The question wasn't off-topic, but you decided that an alternative strategy was better, where that strategy is explained in response to another question and wouldn't work as an answer to this one. If you had still wanted an answer to this question, I wouldn't have voted to close it. Technically, the question is still perfectly fine, but when the asker no longer wants an answer, it is often better to close.

Comment: @cfr Noted, and thank you for the clarification. : j